# How to navigate to ViewController in Xamarin iOS on RowSelected event

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, xamarin.ios, mkmapview, xamarin

I am having a TableView on my home screen which is inside a Navigation Controller. Now, when a row is selected, I want to show a MapView.

I want to get access to the Navigation Controller and push a MapViewController into it. How can i achieve this?

```
public override void RowSelected (UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
{

}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I assume your `RowSelected` method is in your `UITableViewController`, right? In this case, it's easy, as you can access the `NavigationController` property (defined in `UIViewcontroller`) which is automatically set to the parent `UINavigationController`

```cs
public override void RowSelected (UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
{
    var index = indexPath.Row;
    NavigationController.PushViewController (new MyDetailViewController(index));
}
```

Now, you probably should use a `UITableViewSource`, and override `RowSelected` there. In that case, make sure the `UINavigationController` is available by doing constructor injection:

```cs
tableViewController = new UITableViewController();
tableViewController.TableView.Source = new MyTableViewSource (this);

class MyTableViewSource : UITableViewSource
{
    UIViewController parentController;
    public MyTableViewSource (UIViewController parentController) 
    {
        this.parentController = parentController;
    }

    public override int RowsInSection (UITableView tableview, int section)
    {
        //...
    }

    public override UITableViewCell GetCell (UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        //...
    }

    public override void RowSelected (UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        var index = indexPath.Row;
        parentController.NavigationController.PushViewController (new MyDetailViewController(index));
    }
}
```

Replace `MyDetailViewController` in this generic answer by your `MapViewController` and you should be all set.

Comment: Awesome, I could not get direct access to NavigationController as in your first code snippet but the 2nd snipper worked great :)

Comment: So you weren't in a `UIViewController` embedded in a `UINavigationController`.

Comment: I have a separate MyTableViewControllerSource class subclassed from UITableViewSource which contains the RowSelected method. So, I used the constructor as you mentioned in 2nd snippet and it worked for me. I started using Xamarin a couple of days back so am I missing any basic concept here?

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to navigate from IndexViewController To ViewController. I use the following code.

```
IndexViewController owner;

    public override void RowSelected (UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
            {
                UIStoryboard board = UIStoryboard.FromName ("Main", null);
                ViewController ctrl = (ViewController)board.InstantiateViewController ("viewControllerID");
                owner.NavigationController.PushViewController (ctrl, true);
        }
```