# Xamarin iOS RowSelected Event navigate to ViewController

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I have a tableview. I would like when i click on a row to capture row info on a list and pass them on DetailScreen UIViewController. I have create iPhone view controllers with xamarin studio and for the layout i am using Xcode. I am trying the follow code but i am taking error"System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
"
I have tried this solution without success: [How to navigate to ViewController in Xamarin iOS on RowSelected event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19443303/how-to-navigate-to-viewcontroller-in-xamarin-ios-on-rowselected-event)

My code:

```
UIViewController parentController;
public override void RowSelected (UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
{
   var dtscreen = new DetailScreen (mylist);
   parentController.NavigationController.PushViewController(dtscreen,true);// Error System.NullReferenceException
   tableView.DeselectRow (indexPath, true);
   }
```

Comment: You said you want to pass details to another view, but your code tries to push a view controller, what do you really want to do?

Comment: I made update to my question. I want to pass this list on DetailScreen UIViewController

Comment: But DetailsScreen will be a new view or an existing one?

Comment: I am not creating the view controller with code. I have create this view controller using xamarin studio xib and cs files

Comment: What I mean is, do you must instantiate and present there that controller or is already presented?

Comment: Tri this: instead of `parentController.NavigationController.PushViewController(dtscreen,true);` use `PresentViewController(dtscreen, true, null);` and to remove `DismissViewController(true, null);`

Comment: I just instantiate it to pass the list with it. There is no other reason i am instantiating the Details ViewController

Comment: I am taking this error when i try your suggestion :Cannot access non static member of outer type

Comment: oh, ok, sorry, my mistake, do `parentController.PresentViewController(...`

Comment: Now i am taking on this line: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Comment: Well, then your parentController is null, did you set it to anything?

Comment: no. how can i set it?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51434/discussion-between-gusman-and-focus)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please change next part of code:

`public TableSource (List<Item> Items, UIViewController viewController)  
{ 
    _Items= Items; 
    parentController = viewController; 
}`